# Spring Security w/ Nested Accounts

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm having difficulties with authorizing nested accounts in Spring Security. I'm new to Spring Security. I spent around a week to reach a working solution, but it's an ugly one and I'd love to refactor it...

I'm using Spring 4.2.4 and Spring Security 4.0.3.

I have user accounts that look like this:

Office User A

Office User B

Field User C

--> Field Sub-User a

--> Field Sub-User b

Field User D

--> Field Sub-User c

So, an office user has only one account, but a field user has at least one sub-account always, with the potential for two or more sub-accounts. Each sub-account can have different authorities. Like one sub-account can view only, and another sub-account can view plus create.

The user will sign-in with an account (A, B, C, or D). If A or B signs in, there is no issue. However, if user C signs in, they need to pick (a or b) and we need information for their choice. If user D signs in, we need information for user (c). I'm using Spring Security and struggling with getting the information for User a/b/c above. I came to a solution, but it's not ideal, and I'd like to know a more proper way.

My solution:

In the @AuthenticationPrincipal implementation of UserDetails, add below code:

```
private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
private String uniqueId1;
private String uniqueId2;
```

```
public void setAuthorities(Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    if (this.authorities != null) {
        return this.authorities; //CHILD
    }
    return super.getAuthorities(); // (SUPER)
}
```

```
public void setUniqueId1(String uniqueId1) {
    this.uniqueId1 = uniqueId1;
}

public String getUniqueId1() {
    if (this.uniqueId1!= null) {
        return this.uniqueId1; //CHILD
    }
    return super.getUniqueId1(); // (SUPER)
}
```

```
public void setUniqueId2(String uniqueId2) {
    this.uniqueId2 = uniqueId2;
}

public String getUniqueId2() {
    if (this.uniqueId2!= null) {
        return this.uniqueId2; //CHILD
    }
    return super.getUniqueId2(); // (SUPER)
}
```

Then, in my method to get logged-in user information, accept a string of the selected user and do like such:

```
public @ResponseBody FullUserDetails getLoggedInUserInfo(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal MyImplementationOfUserDetails user,
            String selectedUsername)

MyImplementationOfUserDetails user2 = getUserInfo(selectedUsername);

user.setAuthorities(user2.getAuthorities());
user.setUniqueId1(user2.getUniqueId1());
user.setUniqueId2(user2.getUniqueId2());
```

In this way, I am able to 'change' the authorities and unique id properties which would otherwise be unchangeable because they are private in the parent classes and normally only accessible through a constructor. **I tried making a new constructor in the UserDetails implementation**, but when I create a new @AuthenticationPrincipal, **it doesn't override the one in the session.** I think a new constructor would be the most proper way to go. How do I override the @AuthenticationPrincipal in the session with a new UserDetails object? Or is there a better approach entirely, which I'm not thinking of? I just want the **new authorities and unique ID** information for **the sub-user** that was selected to be put into the @AuthenticationPrincipal. The next time I get the @AuthenticationPrincipal, it will then have that information.

The consequences of not getting the new information and putting it in the @AuthenticationPrincipal is that the webpage behavior will be wrong. Mostly because the authority levels will not be correct for the user that was selected.

I was trying to call:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuthenticationObjectHere);
```

But I wasn't seeing the changes after calling setAuthentication()...

The only way I was able to see the changes was by directly calling setters in the MyImplementationOfUserDetails object retrieved from the @AuthenticationPrinciple.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, very confused, but the main idea is almost understandable.

I think you go in cycles with an idea to calculate all complex relations between accounts and after that to give the final account required permission and provide access to some resource.

What if to change the logic of providing access to resources without manipulating the account relations? And the very important chain - to use remote/distributed Authorization server like Spring OAuth2 one? With it, you can have authorities for any account AND scopes (!). Depending on organization conditions an account can have different scopes. And your final resources (usually they are controllers methods) have pre-authentication by scope. According to this idea, you can separate the logic of providing access based on specific of accounts, implementing all logic in DB with accounts.

Maybe it's the wrong idea for your project, for me it works - I change scopes for customers depending their conditions, but not manipulate with their data and relations in runtime.